# Get the data between alphabetic character in c#

Tags: c#

i have a tab control at top of the page. and its value like A to C, D to F and G to Z.

my requirement is when the user click on the tab A to C then he can only see those data which start with A,B or C.

can anyone tell me a way how can i do it?

Comment: *What* data? And where? What are you talking about?

Comment: Where do you show the "data"? do you have a DataGrid or similar and how does the query you use to load the data look like?

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific in telling us what you're doing. For example, is this in an ASP.NET page or Winforms? If it's a web page, are you using WebForms or MVC?

Comment: i have to bind in grid control.

Answer (score 0):

You could try handling the `Selected` event that fires when you change tab, and use that to determine which tab was selected. You can then fill your grid control with the corresponding data.